# Codeigniter session sometimes kicking me out after completing call to a third party API

Tags: codeigniter, session, session-timeout

I got this strange problem for long and have been trying to solve it without any success.
I got a CI site based on CI 1.7.2. It works fine for most of the time. But many a time it does not.

The problem is, we fill up up a form with many fields and submit it to a method in the controller which does the checking. It then posts the data to the third party web service using curl.

I have a error/order response tracker setup, which mails me every time I get response back from the API. The mail content is of the format:

Order ID: 5876 Result length - 8056 or
Order ID: 5877 Result length - 1121 ....and so on for each order.

Now, many a time I get mail like:

Order ID: Result length - 34441   *(Please note the order id is missing here)*
Order ID: Result length - 9700

Now , the code for my mail happens to be

```
mail('myemail@xyz.com','Order ID: '.$this->session->userdata('SITE_ORDER_NO').' Result length - '. $lengthResponse , $orderResult, $headers);
```

So its seems the,

```
$this->session->userdata('SITE_ORDER_NO')
```

segment of the code does not have the Order ID any more. As such the API response is not getting saved in the database . Also I got few reports that the user was logged out of the website after it transferred him to the next page , after the response came back.

My session setup is:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']             = 'cisessionJHGJHSOMECAPITALLETTERS';   
$config['sess_expiration']              = 7200;   
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']          = TRUE;   
$config['sess_use_database']            = TRUE;   
$config['sess_table_name']              = 'user_sessions';   
$config['sess_match_ip']                = TRUE;   
$config['sess_match_useragent']         = TRUE;   
$config['sess_time_to_update']          = 300;
```

The code of the helper function is:

```
function call_order_curl($postVars){  
    $posturl = "API_URL";   
    $ch = curl_init();   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $posturl);   
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,300);   
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,600);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  

    $response = curl_exec($ch);   
    return $response;   
}
```

I would really appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Are your users on mobile devices? I had a similar problem with changing IP's of the users. You could also try reducing the sess_time_to_update. It can increase the load on your server, but you'll know where the problem is :)

Comment: Nope, they are on the regular website.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the cookie in your curl_setopt? You may be using the database, but CodeIgniter still needs to send over a hash via a cookie.

Comment: @Steven Lu, Nope, I ma not setting any cookie.It would be awesome if you can explain this a bit more. The third party API service I am calling does not need any cookie to be sent over though.